# Function split() is deprecated PHP, explode doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms, split

I have downloaded a contact form form the web. On one part (`class.phpmailer.php`) on line 470 it uses:

```
$toArr = split(',', $to);
```

Of course this is depreciated. I have searched the web for answers (and read the php syntax), and it says use `explode()` or `preg_split()`.

I have tried both of these, but when I submit the contact form nothing happens. The data stays but the captcha changes. I also put:

```
$toArr = split('!,!', $to);
```

Again, the form would not submit.

Could somebody please tell me how to fix this ?

EDIT:
The error was nothing to do with explode/preg_split - it was a missing html tag I believe.

Comment: Did you try `$toArr = explode(',', $to)`?

Comment: Use `explode` .. `split` is depreciated

Comment: @Baba OP already knows this.

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes I did. It didn't work, the same problem with the submit button.

Comment: Show your actual coding attempt regarding `explode`.

Comment: @lukecolli98 are you sure that's the only issue?  Maybe you're getting another error that you don't see

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when I submit the contact form nothing happens"? The form doesn't submit/send anything to the server? It does submit, but there is no response from the action page? Or the action page looks correct, but it doesn't do what you expect it to? For that matter, what are you expecting it to do? I'm assuming you want it to send an email... can you clarify the exact goal or link to the source you downloaded?

Comment: is this an ajax form? so please check the console for error messages.

Comment: $toArr = explode (',', $to); DIDN'T WORK $toArr = preg_split (',', $to); GOT ERROR: preg_split(): No ending delimiter ','

Comment: Form from 
http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/creating-a-contact-form.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure your "form not submitting" problem or whatever it is is completely unrelated to using `explode` instead of `split`.

Comment: Maybe it is. What happens is: I fill in all fields and captcha. When I press submit the form stays on the page with all the fields still full of the data I entered, but the captcha goes blank. This happens ONLY when I use explode () but when I use preg_split () I get the delimiter error.

Comment: You get a delimiter error because you aren't providing a valid regular expression pattern.

Comment: Ok, so what should the preg_split code be ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) without problems:

```
$toArr = explode ( ',', $to );
```

Or you can use: [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) or [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php) or

Comment: As I already said, using explode () won't let me sumbit the form.

Comment: This code works fine.
You are getting another error.

Answer (score 2):

split() is indeed deprecated. You should instead use

```
$toArr = explode (',', $to);
```

This should work without problems.

Comment: Most amazing answer ever seen, looking at what the OP said :P (and no I did not -1 you)

Comment: Yep, didn't work. I mentioned above about the problem, this caused the same sumbit problem.

Comment: $toArr = explode (',', $to);
DIDN'T WORK
$toArr = preg_split (',', $to);
GOT ERROR: preg_split(): No ending delimiter ','

Answer (score 0):

```
$toArr = explode(",", $to);
```

or

```
$toArr = explode(',', $to);
```

should work, depending on what you want to do. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php for more information.

The fact that the form doesn't not submit when using explode shouldn't be related to the explode function, and a bug in the form itself is much more likely, but it's impossible to help you just with this bit of code. Please share more of the form code.